# How to Insert Into User Defined Type Column Table

Tags: oracle

I have oracle user defined types and tables which has these types as columns. I am trying to insert simple data into a table that has user defined type column. But i get invalid identifier error. I found a way to insert successfully. But i need simple method for this. Or maybe i did something wrong while creating the table at the beginning.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE SCHEMA.A_TYPE as object
(
    column1 varchar2(4),
    column2 varchar2(5)
)

create table SCHEMA.TABLE1
(
    recordid     NUMBER,
    typedata     SCHEMA.A_TYPE
);
```

First i try to insert like

```
insert schema.table1(recordid, typedata.column1, typedata.column2) 
values (1, 'aaaa', 'bbbbb');
```

But i get invalid identifier for typedata.column1, typedata.column2 column names.

Then i insert like

```
declare
   v_type  schema.a_type := new  schema.a_type('aaaa', 'bbbbb');
begin
   insert into scheme.table1(recordid, typedata)
   values (1, v_type);
   commit;
end;
```

But it is a problem for larger column size tables. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure what "problem for larger column size tables" means.  Your second `insert` statement is correct.  I'm not sure what problem you're having when you try to increase the size.

Comment: I mean types could have more columns. When i export data from db, it gives me insert script like first insert statement that i gave. And i need to convert it to second working insert statement. It takes time. Also in real i use more than one type in table.

Comment: It sounds like you are saying that the real problem is that whatever method you are using to export the data is generating incorrect `insert` statements.  How, exactly, are you generating the statement?  Are you using an Oracle tool?  My guess is that whatever tool/ method you are using wasn't built to support object types in tables.

Comment: `insert into table1 values (1, a_type('aaaa', 'bbbbb'));` is simpler.

Comment: Thank you for all comments. @JustinCave, i use PL/SQL developer v11.0.3. And it doesn't support the object types tables as i understand. Also i have Oracle SQL Developer v1.5.5, and it supports object types in table. It fill the bill :). Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use syntax similar to the following:

```
insert into schema.table1(recordid, typedata)
values ( 1, schema.a_type('aaaa','bbbbb'));
```

The thing to remember is that to insert the object type data you need to use the object constructor.  You can extend that to other forms of the insert statement as well:

```
insert into schema.table1(recordid, typedata)
  select rownum, schema.a_type(owner, object_name)
    from all_objects
   where length(owner) <=4
     and length(object_name) <= 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created an example for:

- create multi level user defined types
- insert into a table with these types
- how to find the path for the attributes of types
- select without variable
- you can find a picture attached with the structure of the types.

---

```
create or replace type place_type as object
(city varchar2(20),
street varchar2(20));

create or replace type birth_type as object
(birth_place place_type,
zipcode number);

create or replace type name_type as object
(fi_name varchar2(20),
la_name varchar2(20));

create table customer_x
(birth_info birth_type,
cust_name name_type);

INSERT INTO customer_x VALUES 
(birth_type(place_type('London', 'Magic Str.'), 5400), name_type('Henry', 'Big'));

select * from customer_x
```

```html
<table style="width:70%">
  <tr>
    <td><b>BIRTH_INFO<b></td>
    <td><b>CUST_NAME<b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>[SCHEMA1.BIRTH_TYPE]</td>
    <td>[SCHEMA1.NAME_TYPE]</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

To find the current values of the columns use the table *USER_TYPE_ATTR*

```
select type_name, attr_name, attr_type_name
from user_type_attrs
where type_name = 'BIRTH_TYPE'
```

```html
<table style="width:70%">
  <tr>
    <td><b>TYPE_NAME<b></td>
    <td><b>ATTR_NAME<b></td>
    <td><b>ATTR_TYPE_NAME<b></td> 
  <tr>
    <td>BIRTH_TYPE</td>
    <td>ZIPCODE</td> 
    <td>NUMBER</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>BIRTH_TYPE</td>
    <td>BIRTH_PLACE</td> 
    <td>PLACE_TYPE</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Let’s find the type PLACE_TYPE:

```
select type_name, attr_name, attr_type_name
from user_type_attrs
where type_name = 'PLACE_TYPE'
```

```html
<table style="width:70%">
  <tr>
    <td><b>TYPE_NAME<b></td>
    <td><b>ATTR_NAME<b></td>
    <td><b>ATTR_TYPE_NAME<b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>PLACE_TYPE</td>
    <td>CITY</td>
    <td>VARCHAR2</td>
  </tr>
  </tr>
    <td>PLACE_TYPE</td>
    <td>STREET</td>
    <td>VARCHAR2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So the correct path is:

```
select a.birth_info.birth_place.city from customer_x a
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6OiB.png)